# Customize Excel chart number axis

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010

I have certain charts in Excel for which the vertical axes are increments of $10million.
It looks like this though: 10000000, 20000000, 30000000,...

I'd like it looking more like : 10Mil, 20Mil, 30Mil. It's much cleaner and more legible.

Any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double-click on the x-axis values in the chart. This should open up a menu where in some tab you'll have the possibility to select a number format. Try:

```
#0,," Mil"
```